# Hourly Date Sequence In R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to produce a sequence of dates at hourly intervals. As an example I tried the following:

```
> seq(as.Date("1912-02-24 23:00:00"), as.Date("1912-02-25 08:32:00"), by="hour")
```

which produces an error, yet it works fine for by= year, month, day.

The documentation for seq.POSIXt {base} states that it should work for hour, sec, min, etc, yet all of these produce an error.

```
> ?seq.POSIXt
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But you have objects of class `"Date"` not `"POSIXt"`! `seq.Date()` would then apply and as this relates to just dates, where the day is the minimum unit of time, how do you expect it to increment the Dates by hours?

Answer (score 23):

Well, don't you give the answer yourself ;-)

What about:

```
seq(as.POSIXct("1912-02-24 23:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1912-02-25 08:32:00"), by="hour")
```

(also works with `as.POSIXlt`).

Comment: what about 4 hourly intervals?

Comment: @DarrenRhodes the unit of `by` is the second. You can do `by=3600 * 4`, or replace `4` by any number of hours you like.

Comment: here's what I did in the end, axis.POSIXct(1, results$sample, at = seq(r[1], r[2], by = "12 hour"), format = "%a\n%H hrs", cex.axis = 0.75, las = 2), noting that by = "12 hour"