# setting xlim and breaks on x axis in plot function

Tags: r, plot

I have a df like this:

```
Value   Time
10      2012-06-23 01:00:00
20      2012-06-23 02:00:00
```

time is formated as `as.PoSIXct(df$Time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

I am trying to set the breaks in axis to show xaxis tick mark every 2 hours as this:

```
plot(df$Time, df$Value, ylim(0,100), xlim(seq(c("2012-06-23 01:00:00", "2012-06-23 23:00:00", 2)))
```

I get invalid xlim value. any ideas?

I have tried this line, still not working:

```
plot(df$Time, df$Value, col="red", type="l", xlab="Date", ylab="% Memory Utilization", xlim=seq(c(as.POSIXct("2012-06-23 01:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2012-06-23 23:00:00"), by="hour")))
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem even specifying xlim = correctly and using POSIXlt formatted dates. I suspect the issue is that R isn't very date-friendly. I solved it with the equivalent of this:

```
my.limits <- c("2012-06-23 01:00:00", "2012-06-23 23:00:00")  # example data
my.limits <- as.numeric(my.limits)  # new step to convert data
plot(..., xlim = my.limits, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems, first is that `xlim` is an argument not a function and that should be `xlim=` rather than `xlim(`, but due to the paren mismatch I expect that is a typo, it is better to copy and paste the actual code that you tried (along with errors, warnings, output, etc.).

Second, the seq function is being passed 2 character strings, not 2 dates, you need to explicitly convert them to dates to pass to the `seq` function so that the correct method is called (and you may need to specify that the 2 refers to hours, not minutes, days, etc.).

If you give us a reproducible example (use `dput` to create data that we can copy and paste) and/or actual output and messages then it makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should try to break your problem down to the essential issue, which is the `xlim` statement, not anything to do with `plot`. What are you actually doing with the `seq` you supply to xlim:

```
> seq(c("2012-06-23 01:00:00", "2012-06-23 23:00:00", 2))
[1] 1 2 3
```

Clearly that is the problem and where you next focus.

Second, then you could search very specifically about creating date sequences in R by hour, which would get you to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887923/hourly-date-sequence-in-r). Applying it to your question is trivial:

```
seq(as.POSIXct("2012-06-23 01:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2012-06-23 23:00:00"), by="hour")
```

Which gives:

```
 [1] "2012-06-23 01:00:00 MDT" "2012-06-23 02:00:00 MDT" "2012-06-23 03:00:00 MDT" "2012-06-23 04:00:00 MDT"
# all the other rows...
[21] "2012-06-23 21:00:00 MDT" "2012-06-23 22:00:00 MDT" "2012-06-23 23:00:00 MDT"
```

Also you are specifying your parameters to the plot function incorrectly. You should be using `xlim=`, not `xlim(...)`.

Comment: the problem is that I can plot this data but the xaxis is not showing all the values. It is only showing couple hours. I would like to show everyhour or maybe every two hours tick marks. I've been looking at this quite a while now, no progress