# How to create Time series from data hourly

Tags: r, time-series

I want to create a time series of hourly data. I use `ts()` in R:

```
series<-ts(data,start=as.Date("2019-9-1 4:00:00 AM"), frequency=24)
```

The result seems to be incorrect.

P/s: Picture is a part of data. All data is in a csv file.( about over 750 rows).

[image]

Comment: Do you need to create an hourly sequence between two points ? So something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887923/hourly-date-sequence-in-r ?

Comment: Please provide you data head as `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: What do you want to do with the result? More information would be helpful. Also, a ts object is not a good choice for hourly data. A tsibble would normally be better.